# How to store a path with white spaces into a variable in bash

Tags: bash, quoting

I want to store `/c/users/me/dir name` into a variable to pass it to `cd` system call.

Works when typing:

`$ cd '/c/users/me/dir name'`

or

`$ cd /c/users/me/dir\ name`

but does not works if I store it:

```
$ dirname="'/c/users/me/dir name'"
$ cd $dirname
$ bash: cd: /c/users/me/dir: No such file or directory
```

the same result to:

```
$ dirname=('/c/users/me/dir name')
```

or

```
$ dirname=(/c/users/me/dir\ name)
```

Which is the right way to store it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Double-quote your path variable with spaces, to preserve it,

```
dirName="/c/users/me/dir name"
cd "$dirName"
```

Actually, `dirname` is a shell built-in, *recommend* using an alternate name to avoid confusion with the actual command.

From the `man bash` page,

> Enclosing characters in double quotes (‘"’) preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of ‘$’, ‘`’, ‘\’, and, when history expansion is enabled, ‘!’.

Comment: Good answer. `dirname` was used as example only.

Comment: @AlexandreThebaldi: Appreciate you finding it helpful!

Answer (score 2):

While using a bash variable you should double-quote it to preserve its state.

```
x='/home/ps/temp/bla bla'
 cd $x      ### <----used without double quotes. 
sh: cd: /home/ps/temp/bla: No such file or directory


 cd "$x"    ### <---While using a bash variable you should double-quote it to presever its state.
 pwd
/home/ps/temp/bla bla
```